# Site unexpectedly closed the connection when in HTTPS

Tags: https, google-chrome

I make no bones about it. I am a noob at websites. 
Saying that I tend to research questions before asking for help.

Today I was working with Hostgator to get SSL on my site. They got it on there and after resolving a conflict I had one biggie remaining. 
All the site images and HTML scripts would not display. The images returned no error but the HTML returned example.net unexpectedly closed the connection.

I repeated the error by changing some of the URLs to HTTPS manually

Hostgator said that this was a google chrome only issue. Anyone know how its fixed?

Comment: when trying to access your website with https in Firefox I got the error SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP you should ask Hostgator to ensure your certificate is well configured.

Comment: "Hostgator said that this was a google chrome only issue." - And what do they mean by that? Do they consider that acceptable?!

Comment: Kewl. thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was the guy who previously owned the site.

To solve the issue, I had to change the links to relative links IE: `/folder/test.html`. All his links had been explicit. For example `https://example.com/folder/test.html`